# Monthly Count with Daily records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I work with credit card accounts. Each day, every account adds a record to our database. There is associated data (not relevant to this), but there is one column that shows a boolean (1,0) if the account is active or now, and the date of that record

The data looks a little like this

```
ACCOUNT     DATA1     DATA2     ISACTIVE      INSERT DATE
1234        XXX       XXXX       1             5/1/2019
1234        XXX       XXXX       1             5/2/2019
1234        XXX       XXXX       1             5/3/2019
1234        XXX       XXXX       1             5/4/2019
5678        XXX       XXXX       1             5/1/2019
5678        XXX       XXXX       1             5/2/2019
5678        XXX       XXXX       1             5/3/2019
5678        XXX       XXXX       1             5/4/2019
```

I am looking to figure a distinct count of accounts that are active per month (based on the 1st of each month) going back about 18 months. I am not sure how to code for this though.

I appreciate any help

Comment: With that sample table data (or updated), specify the expected result as well.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes do date/time, many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Comment: dbms: MSSQL 16
expected results
    May 2017: 1500
    June 2017: 1550  etc

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Count(DISTINCT account) 
FROM   t 
WHERE  isactive = 1 
GROUP  BY Month(insert_date), 
          Year(insert_date)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try grouping on month(INSERT DATE):

```
SELECT month([INSERT DATE]) as month_num,count(distinct ACCOUNT) as ACCOUNT_num
from table
group by month([INSERT DATE])
```

Comment: how would i account for multiple years?

Comment: Others have responded, but you could year([INSERT DATE]) *100 + month([INSERT DATE])) to group by year&month.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT YEAR([INSERT DATE]) AS [Year], MONTH([INSERT DATE]) AS [Month], COUNT(DISTINCT [Account]) AS [UniqueActiveAccounts]
FROM [YourTableName]
WHERE [ISACTIVE] = 1 AND [INSERT DATE] > DATEADD(MONTH,-19,GETDATE())
GROUP BY YEAR([INSERT DATE]), MONTH([INSERT DATE])
```

This query gets data 18 months back from the time you run this query. You can adjust this period in the **DATEADD** part of the query.

You will of course need to insert the name of your table after **FROM**.